# Docker building an image for ELK stack

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I'm new to Docker
Installed the docker on ubuntu 12.04.Now 
I want to install ELK(Elastic search,Logstash and Kibana) on Single container.How can I go with?Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image does exactly that

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/pblittle/docker-logstash/

run it using the following command

```
$ docker run -d -p 9292:9292 -p 9200:9200 pblittle/docker-logstash
```